# Turn off anti-aliasing in Emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs23

I'm using Proggy (`ProggyCleanTTSZ 12` in `.Xdefaults`) font in Emacs. I'm not happy with how my OS (Ubuntu 10.10) applies anti-aliasing to it. How do I disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font rendering is generally handled by the OS libraries rather than the application, so you need to tell Ubuntu not to anti-alias that particular font. It's been a few years since I worked much on Linux, but if things haven't changed, you can configure this by editing a file (maybe something like /etc/fonts/fonts.conf or ~/.fonts.conf or something similar).

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts#Manual_Font_Smoothing might help.

Answer (score 4):

You can set font options in your .Xdefaults (or .Xresources - whichever you are using). This allows you to disable anti-aliasing in emacs, but still have it enabled elsewhere.

```
emacs*font:  ProggyCleanTTSZ-12:antialias=false
```

See also the [fontconfig user guide](http://freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html#AEN36)